# Docker and Rails environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile

Just starting with this whole Docker thing and I can't wrap my head around one thing:

How does one deal with different dependencies? Let's say in production I don't want to have git, grunt, etc installed, but in development I do.

There's a difference between a container that can run tests, and container that runs in production.

Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: I'm not a Rails developer, but in PHP the Composer dependency manager allows you to specify "dev only" dependencies. Then, when it's time to deploy, you do a `composer install --no-dev`. I would imagine Rails has something similar.

Answer (score 2):

There are different philosophies on this, but personally, I use Docker to match my production environment as closely as possible so testing with that container anywhere let's me be pretty sure things will just work once I deploy to prod. This is one of the major benefits of Docker-- that you can mimic OS, environment, dependencies, versions, etc... locally before deploying anywhere.

There's nothing wrong with having a separate container development container with added dependencies that you can pass around your team, but to me the main benefit of Docker for development is the ability to test on that simulated prod environment and run the exact same container locally that you will be using in prod once you're ready. No more "but it worked on my machine!" bugs.

Comment: + you may still run the production-like container during the development, using the extended "development" container for running tests, etc.

Comment: Do you have an example on how to juggle prod vs dev containers?

Comment: @Grocery they'll be based on two different images. You can run both images at once when you need to (using different ports, etc...). For example, if you have dev tagged as '0.0.3-dev' and prod as '0.0.3', you could do: `docker run -p 8006:8006 my_repo/my_container:0.0.3-dev` and at the same time `docker run -p 8007:8007 my_repo/my_container:0.0.3`. Juggling them is simple this way, and you can have either or both available when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

[docker-rails](https://github.com/alienfast/docker-rails) is a project I just created to make rails with docker (and CI) *very easy*.  I think it can help you and reduce the amount of configuration necessary to get up and running with rails on docker.  It deals with multiple environments i.e. `development | test | production` in one `docker-rails.yml` file, which is really just a meta configuration/inheritance wrapper over the standard docker-compose.yml.

It will allow you to run a test command set in test, vs development server, or a production setup with different containers.  The example in the readme shows `elasticsearch` used in dev and test, but not staging or production.

I hope that helps.